# ASP.Net MVC keeps calling the index action method for each controller action method I call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having a problem either with my routing config file or something else in the Asp.Net MVC app that keeps triggering each index action method in every controller I visit. If I click the action link below I will be taken to the page /profile/general, see the view results rendered on the screen, but then something in the app, not sure what, triggers the index action to be called on that controller! Being that I don't have index action methods on most of the controllers I end up getting exceptions visiting each page.

ex. I click the action link below

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "general", "profile", new { }, new { @class = "btn-sm", @style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: 1em;" })
```

or just refresh the browser.
I enter into the general action method seen below

```
public ActionResult General()
    {
        try
        {
            ViewBag.MenuItem = "profile";
            ViewBag.UserMenuItem = "general";

            var viewModel = _yogaProfileService.GetGeneralInfo(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _errorService.LogError(ex, Request);
            ViewBag.Message = "Oh No! Something went wrong fetching your info. We're looking into this now!";
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

the view gets called and I see it on the page, but then something calls the index method on that same controller and I step into the index action method here.  The debugger enters into the method below. It doesn't render the index's view on the screen, I still see the general view, so not sure what's going on here!

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            ViewBag.MenuItem = "profile";
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _errorService.LogError(ex, Request);
            ViewBag.Message = "Oh No! Something went wrong fetching your profile. We're looking into this now!";
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

of course I just have the index method here for display reasons, so in the app I have it removed, so I get an exception thrown on almost every page I visit because it looks for a index action method on each controller I visit

> System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'Index' was not found on controller 'YogaBandy2017.Controllers.ProfileController'.

I don't know if it's a routing issue or something else? I tried looking in the debugger to see the networking to determine what was calling the index, and also in the call stack but it just says 'external' is it possible some Javascript is calling it, if so, how would I look for this?

Here is my routing file

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RateRoute",
            url: "rate/event/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "rate", action = "event" },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SpaceCleanRoute",
            url: "space/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "space", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PublicSpaceRoute",
            url: "space/public/{title}",
            defaults: new { controller = "space", action = "public" },
            constraints: new { title = @"^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
}
```

UPDATE - I only see it in IE, Chrome and Firefox don't have my issue 
Here is a pic of my debugger showing the pending request

[image]

UPDATE2 - I don't believe it's a Javascript issue, if I don't load the .js file the index still gets called. So I don't believe it has anything to do with Javascript

Comment: Have you turned on Chrome debugging tools ( network tab) or used Fiddler and watched the network traffic attempt to request the Index action on the ProfileController? If it's a JavaScript call, you should be able to capture it in either debugging tool.

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome and the index action method wasn't being called. Only in IE is it calling the Index action method! weird!!

Comment: Fire up the IE debugging tools, set a breakpoint on the index controller, open up the IE network tab, navigate to the problematic general view from the ProfilerContoller. When the index request hits your breakpoint, got back to IE and check for any pending XHR requests.

Comment: ok hold up let my try

Comment: ok so I've hit the breakpoint in the index method and I see the pending request in the debugger, now what? what can I look for? I don't know if it's a XHR request, in the initiator/type area I see 'XMLHttpRequest', maybe it's because I'm using HTTPS?

Comment: I posted a pic of the request in the debugger

Comment: Can you search the rendered view for for "Profile"?

Comment: let's move to chat...

Comment: what exactly do you mean "Profile", profile is my controller name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169516/discussion-between-brennan-mann-and-user1186050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussions in the Stackoverflow chat, we discovered that IE 11 was triggering a call to the default action for the following:

```
<link href="" rel="icon">
```

IE was generating XMLHttpRequest to the Controller's default action.

This is occurring in IE 11.

By removing the empty `href=""`, we were able to resolve the issue.

The following was the solution:

```
<link rel="icon">
```

Per the HTML5 preview spec:

https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-link-element.html#attr-link-href

> The destination of the link(s) is given by the href attribute, which
>   must be present and must contain a valid non-empty URL potentially
>   surrounded by spaces. If the href attribute is absent, then the
>   element does not define a link.
>
> The types of link indicated (the relationships) are given by the value of the rel attribute, which, if present, must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens. The allowed keywords and their meanings are defined in a later section. If the rel attribute is absent, has no keywords, or if none of the keywords used are allowed according to the definitions in this specification, then the element does not create any links.
>
> Two categories of links can be created using the link element: Links
>   to external resources and hyperlinks. The link types section defines
>   whether a particular link type is an external resource or a hyperlink.
>   One link element can create multiple links (of which some might be
>   external resource links and some might be hyperlinks); exactly which
>   and how many links are created depends on the keywords given in the
>   rel attribute. User agents must process the links on a per-link basis,
>   not a per-element basis
>
> The exact behavior for links to external resources depends on the
>   exact relationship, as defined for the relevant link type. Some of the
>   attributes control whether or not the external resource is to be
>   applied (as defined below).
>
> For external resources that are represented in the DOM (for example,
>   style sheets), the DOM representation must be made available even if
>   the resource is not applied. To obtain the resource, the user agent
>   must run the following steps:
>
> 1. If the href attribute's value is the empty string, then abort these steps.
> 2. Resolve the URL given by the href attribute, relative to the
>      element.
> 3. If the previous step fails, then abort these steps.
> 4. Fetch the resulting absolute URL.

With that being said, IE11 does not appear to be aborting the steps defined above due to an empty "href" value... It continues to resolve the external resource as defined in step 4.

There is some chatter on this with Edge.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8088887/